# Vector Field With Elliptical Form?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-fields

[image]

I was doing some research when I found out this vector field, and I couldn't find its equations nowhere. How could I get the equation that describes this vector field, using only vector calculus and linear algebra (if it is possible)?

**Edit:**
The equation of an ellipse in polar coordinates is the following:
$$
r(\theta)=\frac{\mu}{1 + \varepsilon \cos\theta} \rightarrow r(\theta) \;(1 + \varepsilon \cos\theta) = \mu \rightarrow r + r\varepsilon \cos\theta = \mu \\
$$
Transforming into cartesian coordinates:
$$
\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} + \varepsilon x=\mu 
$$
And rearrange to do an implicit derivtion, arriving to:
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{\mu \varepsilon + x (1 - \varepsilon^2)}{y}
$$

So this is the slope each of the vectors in the field should have. What I should do next?

Comment: Well one thing you could do is consider a shot gun wedding of two multivariable functions $F(x,y,z) = g(x,y,z) \hat{i} + q(x,y,z) \hat{j}$ and do interpolation by considering the component of vector field

Comment: The fact that you have no numeric values assigned makes it hard to assign any specific values to the system.  That looks to me like the flow resulting from a system of differential equations of the form dx/dt= f(x,y), dy/dt= g(x,y) with both f= 0 and g= 0 at the point inside all of those ellipses.

Comment: Closed curves are likely to be the level curves of some function $z = F(x,y)$.  They cannot be the gradient of such a function because the function increases in the direction of the gradient, so going around the curve would imply constantly increasing along a closed trajectory.

Answer (score 1):

The picture suggests that the vector field consists of the vectors that are ***tangential*** to those lines where a function $f(x,y)$ defined on $\mathbb R^2$ is constant. We know that the gradient of $f$ is ***orthogonal*** to those lines.
Therefore I think a way to calculate the vector field is to set it to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}\displaystyle-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\\\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \end{pmatrix}.
$$